# Evaluating $\sum_{n \geq 1}\ln \!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) \!\ln\!\left(1+\frac1{2n+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, logarithms, closed-form

Is there a direct way to evaluate the following series?

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln \!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) \!\ln\!\left(1+\frac1{2n+1}\right)=\frac12\ln^2 2. \tag1
> $$

I've tried *telescoping sums* unsuccessfully. The convergence is clear. Given the simplicity of the result, I'm inclined to think it might exist an elegant way to get $(1)$.

Comment: Your instinct seems good, but I couldn't make telescoping sums work either....

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist: Can you please provide the link to the source? Thank you! :)

Comment: @PranavArora I think I mixed up the problems.

Comment: Another interesting one would be $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln^2 \!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) \!\ln^2\!\left(1+\frac1{2n+1}\right).$$

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use:
$$\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)\right)^2=\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)+\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)+2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)-\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)\right)$$
Therefore, the sum in the given problem is:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)\right)$$

Notice that all the terms of the first sum are cancelled by the other two sums except $n=1$, hence our answer is:
$$\boxed{\dfrac{1}{2}\ln^22}$$

Comment: Very nice solution! If you don't mind my asking, how did you come up with the idea of rewriting it in terms of that binomial square? I got caught up directly simplifying with properties of logs, and that got me nowhere.

Comment: I thought that maybe I could just somehow split the logs. Seeing the product, I immediately thought of $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ and the fact that $(1+\frac{1}{2n})(1+\frac{1}{2n+1})=1+\frac{1}{n}$ also helped. :)

Comment: @PranavArora Well done! (+1) and accepted!

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Thank you! :)

Comment: This was very well done!  +1 ... So simple and elegant.